# What are some technologies for providing subscription services?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am working on a service and would like to provide it for a monthly fee. I've considered accepting physical payments and then manually managing the subscription database, but that sounds shady in my opinion, and not at all scalable or practical.

What are some platforms or frameworks that help with the process of processing the actually transaction and managing this kind of thing? I've heard of Magento, but that's about the extent of my knowledge of the subject.

I really have no idea what kind of level of abstraction are provided for this kind of thing. The application is being developed in PHP, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's SaaSy.com for downloadable products and subscription-based services, it's all-inclusive.

Comment: Thank you Dan! I've looked at SaaSy and am seriously considering using it. Of all the alternatives, it appears to be the best.

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon FPS](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)

[Paypal's Recurring Billing Service](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-recurring-billing-overview-outside)

[chargify.com](http://chargify.com/)

[authorize.net's Automated Recurring Billing™](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/automatedrecurringbilling/)

I'm sure there are more if you care to Google a bit.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! Can you recommend any of these over the others?

Comment: I actually have not used any of them yet - I just did the research a while back for a startup concept I had that still hasn't gone anywhere as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another one is http://zuora.com